# Using Zuul as reverse proxy for Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4, netflix-zuul

I want to have custom authentication before going to a product from the company elastic called Kibana. When creating basic route using the spring-cloud integration with Zuul I can get a lot of services to work. Having an angular app delivered through the proxy works fine, having elasticsearch call go through the proxy, no problem. A spring controller also works without problems.

No I want to start the Kibana server using port 5601 on the localhost. The result is an encoded string, to bad no Kibana web interface. The Kibana tool is an angularjs app interfacing with elasticsearch.

Does someone know why I get the encoded string? Anyone tried the same, Zuul in front of Kibana?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is an issue with the spring-cloud project and the zuul integration. Created a pull request to overcome this problem. Is has to do with the response header which is called content-encoding instead of Content-Encoding.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/pull/663